# Can't post edit with NULL (U+0000) character in Stack Snippet

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

When a Stack Snippet contains a NULL (U+0000) character in its body, various errors start to arise:

- Automatic POST requests to `/posts/validate-body` return a *418 No Reason Phrase* error.
- Trying to run the snippet the request to `https://stacksnippets.net/js` results in a 500 Internal Server Error.
- Trying to save an edit the request to `/posts/[post-id]/edit-submit/` results in a 418 error too.
- The "Review your Question" request to `/posts/validate-question` results in a 418 error.
- Trying to post a question the request to `/questions/ask/submit` results in a 418 error.
- ...

This doesn't seem to happen when this character is present anywhere else in the post; only in the content of a Stack Snippet.

I am not sure how bad it is. It happened to me because I added the results of a console's log as a comment in the JavaScript code, but one can certainly live without the ability to do this, or with this character getting replaced by � (U+FFFD) like it does anywhere else in the post body.

That said, I feel it was quite hard to find what was causing this issue, I guess at least the error message could be clearer, and well, I'm a bit scared by so many teapots in my console.

---

For the ones who want to try, here is a way to get this character:

```js
console.log("copy this:\`" + new TextDecoder().decode(new Uint8Array([0])) + "\`");
```

Paste it anywhere in a Stack Snippet and try to run the snippet.

Comment: The real bug, of course, is that 418 is getting mapped to "No Reason Phrase". It's supposed to be "I'm a Teapot".

Comment: @CodyGray breach of the Hyper Text Coffee Pot Control Protocol (HTCPCP) should be punishable by forcefully depriving the guilty party of coffee or beverage of equal value to the person.